# How to echo a position of a .txt?

Tags: php, date, comparison

I'm doing a code based on two .txt, one with names and the other with birthdays. I'm reading them and when the day date coincides with the date.txt, the name in the coincident line of the names.txt will be shown, but when I do the comparison, only the last line of the names.txt appears.

That's the code:

```
<?php

    $nome   =   fopen("nome.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($nome)){
        $pessoa =   fgets($nome);
    }   fclose($nome);

    $current    =   date("d-m");
    $content    =   fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while (!feof($content)){
        $linha  = fgets($content);
        if (strtotime($linha)   ==  strtotime($current))   {
            echo $pessoa;
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }   fclose($content);

    ?>
```

Content of the .txt:

---

nome.txt:

teste

teste1

teste2

teste3

---

data.txt:

12-12

18-12

12-12

12-12

Comment: well that is because you loop through the whole file overwriting `$pessoa` every time new line found. you probably want to save it to an array instead

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: or you could loop through both files at the same time

Comment: I'm new to php and don't know how to do pass for an array position every loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process line by line from both files at the same time

```
<?php

    $nome    =   fopen("nome.txt", "r");
    $content =   fopen("data.txt", "r");
    $current =   date("d-m");

    while(!feof($nome) && !feof($content)){
        $pessoa =   fgets($nome);
        $linha  = fgets($content);

        if (trim($current) == trim($linha))   {
            echo $pessoa;
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }   

    fclose($content);
    fclose($nome);

?>
```

Or you can read entire file into an array using [file function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) but this may be slower

```
<?php

    $nome    =   file("nome.txt");
    $content =   file("data.txt");
    $current =   date("d-m");

    foreach($content as $key => $linha)

        if (trim($current) == trim($linha))   {
            echo $nome[$key];
            echo '<br>';
        }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the files and load them in to arrays and use foreach with $key to output them in sync.

```
$names = explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents("none.txt"));

$dates = explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents("data.txt"));

Foreach($names as $key => $name){

     Echo $name . " " . $dates[$key] . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/59ao6

Another way is to combine the two arrays in to one.
This however has a flaw, you can not have two people with the same name.

```
$days = array_combine($names, $dates);
// Days is now an associate array with name as key and date as birthday.
Foreach($days as $name => $date){

     Echo $name . " " . $date . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What did not work? In what way did it not work? What did you try? What failed?